# omnetpp mingwenv doesn't work, IDE does

Tags: omnet++

Omnetpp 5.0 Windows 10

I used successfully omnetpp for a few months, but suddenly *mingwnev* is not working anymore.
When I double-click on mingwenv.cmd, it immediately closes without any error message. I am still able to use the IDE, but I really need to use the shell.
Do you have any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Try to start the program from cmd and check possible error messages.

Comment: I found this error: /usr/bin/mintty: could not detach from caller